# Howto exclude xml documentation files from referenced packages in published output

Tags: .net-core, msbuild

I have a reference to `System.Reactive` in my project `<PackageReference Include="System.Reactive" Version="4.4.1" />`

When I publish this I get a 3MB xml documentation file that I don't need in my published output. Anybody has any idea how to exclude these files from the published output?

And I don't mean setting `<GenerateDocumentationFile>false</GenerateDocumentationFile>`, because I need the documentation files of my own projects to be published for Swagger documentation.

Update

I publish using the `dotnet publish` command:

`dotnet publish -c Release .\src\***.csproj -o $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory) -r linux-x64`

Comment: How did you publish the app? In MS docker containers nuget doesn't use xml documentation files

Comment: Does `dotnet publish -c Release .\src\***.csproj -o $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory) -r linux-x64 -p:GenerateDocumentationFile=false` command  work?

Comment: No because I need the documentation of my own projects for the Swagger OpenAPI documentation. I only want to exclude the xml doc from referenced packages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set [`PublishReferencesDocumentationFiles`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/project-sdk/msbuild-props#publishreferencesdocumentationfiles) to false.

Comment: To exclude it set this property to `false`